# in Flutter "Receive share intent" in IOS not receiving any value

Tags: swift, flutter, flutter-getx

here Im using Receive_share_intent package to receive data from other apps it works perfetctly on android but in IOS when i share in IOS it Opens the app but no data has been passed it doesn't triggered the StreamSubcriber too
Package: [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent)
this the package i have been using to receive data

here the i try to get value from the ReceiveSharingIntent to _textReceiveIntent for text and _mediaReceiveIntent for media files but both are not getting any values
fuctions not event triggered will null or [] empty

```
_intentDataStreamSubscription =
        ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((String value) {
      _textReceiveIntent(value);
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getLinkStream error: $err");
    });
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialText().then((String? value) {
      _textReceiveIntent(value);
    });
    // Listen image/video Stream - while app is in foreground
    _intentDataStreamSubscription = ReceiveSharingIntent.getMediaStream()
        .listen((List<SharedMediaFile> value) {
      _mediaReceiveIntent(value);
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("getIntentDataStream error: $err");
    });
    //fetch image/video - while resume from terminate state
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialMedia().then((List<SharedMediaFile> value) {
      _mediaReceiveIntent(value);
    });
```

here What i expecting is receive data from ReceiveSharingIntent to value pass through the respective medium functions

Comment: Hi, did you find out how to make it work. I am currently in the same situation where my Share Extension is opening my Flutter app when I'm trying to share an image but the package is not returning any data.

Comment: Also experiencing  the same issue. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing only URLs from external apps to my flutter app and it's working perfectly fine on my side

Solution:

add receive sharing intent package to you **pubspec.yaml** file, there is a trick

**IMPORTANT NOTE** - to make [receive_sharing_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sharing_intent) functional on IOS just dump the [fork](https://github.com/AyushmanG26/receive_sharing_intent) and use version {{1.4.5}} (don't use ^1.4.5) as versions grater than 1.4.5 doesn't compatible with android's fork
and for Android Build use the below mentioned fork as {{1.4.5}} is not compatible with latest Gradle, Kotlin versions

*bellow is the fork for android*

```
receive_sharing_intent:
    git:
        url: https://github.com/AyushmanG26/receive_sharing_intent
        ref: master
```

*bellow is the version for IOS*

```
receive_sharing_intent: 1.4.5
```

Now as I am just receiving URL bellow is the code to receive intent

```
  Future<void> bindShareIntent(BuildContext context) async {
    // For sharing or opening urls/text coming from outside the app while the app is in the memory
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getTextStream().listen((String value) {
      saveUrl(context, value); // value contains the shared URL
    }, onError: (err) { 
      debugPrint("$err");
    });

    // For sharing or opening urls/text coming from outside the app while the app is closed
    ReceiveSharingIntent.getInitialText().then((String? value) {
      saveUrl(context, value); // value contains the shared URL
    });
  }
```

***I hope you have done other steps already for both android and IOS according to plugin's documentation***

If this solution doesn't work, I will share complete implementation for Both android and IOS